# Pop Up with html or javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, html

Can i bring a pop up to the front but just to show information, like windows live messenger alerts, so if somebody is in another program thats not the web can the alert show info of the web.

Comment: Fortunately, it is not possible

Comment: Actually this is possible with chrome desktop notifications.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) article on HTML5 notifications.

The only browser supporting this now is Chrome and the HTML working group has already announced this feature is candidate to be dropped due to lack of implementation.

So if it is okay for you to just support Chrome: go ahead. Else wise: lose the notifications.